# Is there a name for connected graphs $G$ in which every vertex $v$ has a unique vertex $v'$ at distance $d$ where $d$ is the diameter of $G$?

Tags: graph-theory

Alternatively, what is known about such graphs?

Examples are cycle graphs $C_{2n}$ as well as the Platonic graphs (except of course the tetrahedral graph $K_4$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They could be called antipodal. But be warned, this term is often used for graphs where "is equal to or at distance $d$ from" is an equivalence relation. So under this usage, the line graph of the Petersen graph is antipodal with five antipodal classes of size tree.

Comment: Thanks very much for this hint. The graphs I am looking at are in fact what Miquel Fiol calls "2-antipodal"; and there seem to be a few results known about them.